# Connecting to postgres on command line works, but not with PDO

Tags: postgresql, pdo

I have a working login on the command line to my Postgres server:

```
psql -h127.0.0.1 -Upostgres --password -dDATABASE
```

but, when I try to use it through PDO, it doesn't work:

```
new PDO("pgsql:dbname=DATABASE;host=127.0.0.1;port=5432", "postgres", "PASSWORD");
```

and I get this message:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Permission denied\n\tIs the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was SE Linux. You have to explicitly allow Apache to access the database:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

Comment: For tomcat: `setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db 1` and `systemctl stop tomcat` and `systemctl start tomcat`.

Answer (score 0):

The username and password parameters in the PDO constructor are a slightly odd design mostly used for MySQL. For Postgres, and most other drivers, you should [include those parameters in the DSN, as shown in the examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php):

```
new PDO("pgsql:dbname=DATABASE;host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;user=postgres;password=PASSWORD");
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Besides, I cannot add my `$opt` array.